# Component String to be evaluated by RouterLink in Template (Angular)

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm trying to get [RouterLink] to evaluate an object in *ngFor that has a **string** value of the code that needs to be evaluated.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of ComponentVar">
      [RouterLink]="item.routerLink"
>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Component

```
export Component {
  public ComponentVar [
    { name: 'List Item', routerLink: "['', { outlets: { 'app-popup': ['popupComponent'] } }]", index: 4 },
  ]
}
```

Whenever I look at the Router Logs though it shows an encoded version of this. e.g.

`url: "/path/%5B''%2C%20%7B%20outlets%3A%20%7B%…pp-popup'%3A%20%5B'popupComponent'%5D%20%7D%20%7D%5D"`

How can I get the RouterLink to evaluate it so the route works and the url log will be:

`/path/(app-popup:popupComponent)`

Answer (score 0):

For just the evaluation of a string, by sending an already formated url I managed to get good results `only` when I'm `not` giving an `outlet`. It looks like there is a problem with the router parser somewhere. (in your example shouldnt you send item.routerLink and not item.value ?)

Component.ts

```
 public test = "/update-manager/applications/(view2:new)";
```

Template.html

```
<button [routerLink]="test">test</button>
```

Result

```
<button ng-reflect-router-link="/update-manager/applications/(">test</button>
```

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant item.routerLink. Had updated the question. In my code though I need to use a named router outlet, which is why I'm trying to evaluate the link parameters array.

Comment: Nevermind I got it working after a huge facepalm to myself. I have enough control in the project to pass the item as an array so I removed the string quotations in the object. Thanks for the feedback : )

Comment: Yeah much easier to send an array :)
By the way I'm suprised that there is no way to send a route with an outlet by string